# Everything seems slow!

Tags: 20.04

I changed my Windows 7 system to Ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS) this week mainly to have a speedy system for my works (React, node, etc).
But, now am finding my system even slower to process basic things, like opening a Firefox! I have tried to update my software, but that didn't made any changes.

[image]

These are my system configuration now, it's a bit old, but i think it have enough power to run Ubuntu smoothly.

Does anyone have any clue on what might be causing the slowness? should i try a re-installation?

If there's no way, i will have to go back Windows again! Right now, even booting up is slower than Windows!

Comment: @karel thanks for the link, let me check it one by one. will update here then.

Comment: Ubuntu really should not be slow with the specs of your system. I would suggest you to try Xubuntu, a lighter variant of Ubuntu.